# Trying to install Windows on a system that has Ubuntu 12.04 installed

Tags: partition, system-installation, windows, dual-boot

I'm a novice in installing & debugging OS errors. I had Windows 7 installed & it crashed today (the great blue screen). No matter what I did (tried to install Windows 7 again & again from DVD), I kept getting the blue screen with different types of errors like:

- bad pool header,
- registry error,
- page table trying to access non-page table error, etc.

I had to use my system so I installed Ubuntu. It removed Windows 7 from `C:` drive & I could access my `D:` & `E:` drives, so took the backup. Then tried to install Windows 7 again, but I got blue screen. So, I installed Ubuntu again & removed everything, so it took all my 320 GB HDD space.

Then I tried to create partitions using gparted (with the intent that I would be able to install Windows 7 in one of those) & made some free space, then created the 3 partitions. Don't know what I did, but it made Ubuntu crash when I restarted it. Got `unknown filesystem, grub rescue` error. No idea what to do, so formatted the whole drive again, now running Ubuntu.

Ran gparted again & now my info is like this:

```
Partition: /dev/sda1, File system: ext4, Mount Point: /, Size: 292.17GiB, Used: 8.23GiB, Unused: 283.95Gib, Flags: boot.
```

I tried to create a partition again, but it won't allow me to resize. I guess because it is the only drive & Ubuntu is mounted on it, not sure. Using Windows DVD to install eventually results in blue screen.

So, I basically want to run Windows again & have absolutely no idea what to do. Please give me some step by step instructions as I have no experience with this & not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Are you running gparted on the same filesystem that you're using to run Ubuntu? It sure sounds like it...

Comment: @ChrisDown Yes. I read in some forum that I need to boot via CD & then I could create partitions. I have been able to achieve that but when I try to run my win7 DVD, it gives me the blue screen (most  often the error is bad pool header) after I click on Install Now. Please help.

Comment: @MdT, please tell us how did you resolve the situation :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your place, I would:

1. Create a Ubuntu live USB (or CD/DVD). Lots of ways to do that, but it's easyest under Ubuntu.
2. Do a BIOS "Restore to factory setting"
3. Boot from the Ubuntu liveCD and, using *gparted*, partition the whole HDD to one large NTFS partition. Note that this way you will avoid the windows' 100MB "System Reserved" partition. Shut down.
4. Try to install Windows off a known to work CD/USB.

If you have problems with Windows, try another CD/USB, or another Windows version (if possible; e.g. Windows 7). If you have problems with Ubuntu, use Ubuntu 10.04 LiveCD - IMO this is quite stable on a large range of hardware.

If all fails, gather more concrete data and update your question or ask another.

If it works, I recommend you to take a deep breath and consider creating a dual-boot system (while you have not yet configured your Windows).

Comment: `gparted` is not installed by default under some(all) Ubuntu distributions. This can be handled by using a liveUSB flash drive with the option for persistent data when created. Then boot from it and `sudo apt-get install gparted`. Alternatively, there is [fdisk](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/amd64/partition-programs.html)